# How to obtain the gradient of a function wrt a vector?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm new to mathematica and I wanted to obtain the gradient of the following function:

[image: Equation]

where b_k(s) is the cubic B-spline basis function associated with control point
k.

I tried this code:

```
q = Table[Symbol["q" <> ToString@i], {i, 10}];

y [s_, q_] = Sum[BSplineBasis[3, i, s] * q[[i]], {i, 10}]

dy[s_, q_] = D[y[s], s]

dy2[s_, q_] = D[dy[s], s]

ki[s_, q_] = (dy * dy2)/ dy^3

Ebend [s_, q_, kbend_, li_] = kbend * li * Integrate[ki^2, {s, 0, 1}]

Grad[Ebend[s, q, kbend, li], q]
```

but the output is just a list of zeros.

I tried different ways without defining q but it just rewrites the equation instead of calculating the gradient.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `D[vectorexpression, {vector,1}]`

Comment: You define functions like `ki` and `dy`, but when you call them you don't supply arguments. Because of that, the functions don't evaluate.